# Rails I18n localication

Tags: internationalization

I am developing a multilingual website in Ruby On Rail very first time, that's why i am converting a label of the forms of the website in different language like this <%=t (:artist) %> <%=t (:name) %>, can we translate this variable in one line like <%=t (:artist, :name) %>, actually when i use it give me error.

/var/www/musicradio/trunk/app/views/musicuploads/_searchtype.html.erb:17: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
...put_buffer.append= (t (:artist,:or) );@output_buffer.append=...
...                               ^

Please help me....

Comment: The question is missing the [tag:ruby-on-rails] tag.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if you Group translations instead of translating markup.

Instead of having two separate tags, use this in your en.yml

```
  log_in_or_sign_up:
    text: "%{log_in} or %{sign_up} to do stuff."
    log_in: "Log in"
    sign_up: "Sign up"
```

Then on the .erb

```
<%= t(
  :'log_in_or_sign_up.text',
  log_in:  link_to(t(:'log_in_or_sign_up.log_in'),  login_path),
  sign_up: link_to(t(:'log_in_or_sign_up.sign_up'), signup_path)
) %>
```

More info: http://thepugautomatic.com/2012/07/rails-i18n-tips/

Comment: Thanks for help brother... But its not working, i just add these code in my en.yml and then i use this line in erb
<%=t(:'log_in_or_sign_up.log_in',:'log_in_or_sign_up.sign_up') %>
because i need only this. But its again not working...